# In Xamarin.Forms iOS, Getting HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request when locking the device

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

In Xamarin Forms iOS, I have page and populate some information by fetching data from API. While launching the page, I make the API call on Appearing event. At that time, before completing the page loading, locking the device. In that time, I'm facing HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. The exception details are below,

```
System.Net.WebConnection.CreateStream (System.Net.WebOperation operation, System.Boolean reused, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00208] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnection.cs:234
at System.Net.WebConnection.InitConnection (System.Net.WebOperation operation, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000f7] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnection.cs:263 
at System.Net.WebOperation.Run () [0x00052] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebOperation.cs:268 
at System.Net.WebCompletionSource`1[T].WaitForCompletion () [0x00094] in <3a248b3a8d824cb189d202decc560ac6>:0 
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.RunWithTimeoutWorker[T] (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] workerTask, System.Int32 timeout, System.Action abort, System.Func`1[TResult] aborted, System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource cts) [0x000f8] in <3a248b3a8d824cb189d202decc560ac6>:0 
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00019] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:1200 
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1[TResult].FromAsyncCoreLogic (System.IAsyncResult iar, System.Func`2[T,TResult] endFunction, System.Action`1[T] endAction, System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] promise, System.Boolean requiresSynchronization) [0x0000f] in <a6e593f3cb7d44ddb2035eb114e94ff7>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- 
at System.Net.Http.MonoWebRequestHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x003d1] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/MonoWebRequestHandler.cs:495
```

Please find API request code below,

```cs
private async Task<MyObject> Sample(string requestUri)
{
    var client = new HttpClient
    {
        Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)
    };

    var response = await client.GetStringAsync(requestUri);

    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
        MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore
    };

    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(response, settings);
}
```

Note: In Android, it's working fine.

Comment: Basically, iOS is cancelling the HTTP request when the phone closes. To handle this maybe create an onSleep method that either manually cancels the request or sets up a request to be sent when the phone is next turned on: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/app-lifecycle

Comment: If API is canceled, then that's not a problem. But getting HttpRequestExpception, so I can't able to handle it. Is there any other way to handle it?

Comment: Use a try catch around it and specifically catch HttpRequestExceptions

Comment: @GanesanVG Hi , if answer be solved , remember to mark it when you have time :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a try catch:

```
private async Task<MyObject> Sample(string requestUri)
{
    try{
        var client = new HttpClient
        {
            Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)
        };

        var response = await client.GetStringAsync(requestUri);

        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
            MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore
        };

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(response, settings);
    }
    catch(HttpRequestExceptions ex){

        return default;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fist of all you are using HttpClient in wrong way. This will lead to multiple request and that can generate errors that can crash your app. Next you should check in iOS project options which http client implementation you are using. If you are making https calls make sure that tls version is properly handled by http client implementation. Keep in mind that default managed implementation can handle only tls 1.0.

References:

[MS Documentation HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8)

[Article ASP.NET Monsters](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)

[MS Documentation iOS HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/http-stack)

Comment: Can you please suggest me the best way to do this? Any references?